# Convert CSV data for use with CandleStickChart

Tags: import, csv-format

can anyone show me an example of how to import a CSV file and produce and CandlestickcChart using the imported data.

I have tried

```
data = Import["book1.csv"] // Dataset
```

The data is in the following format:

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
15/10/10 0:00   1.40237 1.40294 1.40165 1.40284 177.0999994
15/10/10 0:05   1.4029  1.4029  1.40133 1.4017  141.7000002
15/10/10 0:10   1.4016  1.40218 1.40059 1.40206 204.0000004
15/10/10 0:15   1.40202 1.40229 1.4014  1.40194 171.8000001
15/10/10 0:20   1.402   1.40235 1.40177 1.40191 122.9000005
```

and then `CandleStickChart[data]` which produces the following error:

> CandlestickChart::ldata:
>   {{Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume},<<49>>,<<451>>} is not a valid
>   dataset or list of datasets.

I'm unsure as to what I need to do to create valid Dataset. I'm using version 11.3

## Update

Here is an example of the CSV file:

Here's a link to file https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhaccQOwpczgpqEnY-HoQR2nTFAcHw

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
15/10/10 0:00,1.40237,1.40294,1.40165,1.40284,177.0999994
15/10/10 0:05,1.4029,1.4029,1.40133,1.4017,141.7000002
15/10/10 0:10,1.4016,1.40218,1.40059,1.40206,204.0000004
15/10/10 0:15,1.40202,1.40229,1.4014,1.40194,171.8000001
15/10/10 0:20,1.402,1.40235,1.40177,1.40191,122.9000005
15/10/10 0:25,1.40206,1.40229,1.40141,1.40169,199.4999995
15/10/10 0:30,1.40179,1.40231,1.40111,1.40199,190.0000001
15/10/10 0:35,1.40202,1.40214,1.40127,1.40174,127.0000005
15/10/10 0:40,1.40177,1.40178,1.40116,1.40163,145.6
15/10/10 0:45,1.40167,1.40242,1.40157,1.40218,160.5000002
15/10/10 0:50,1.40207,1.40253,1.40181,1.40234,335.3000003
15/10/10 0:55,1.40243,1.40354,1.40195,1.40347,156.6999996
15/10/10 1:00,1.40345,1.40399,1.40323,1.40354,226.3000011
15/10/10 1:05,1.40343,1.40429,1.40328,1.40411,229.8000007
```

Comment: Can you put a link to "book1.csv" (or a sample of it)?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of `CandlestickChart`? It tells you exactly what format it expects… To get you started: Look at the output of `{#,{#2,#3,#4,#5}}&@@@Rest@data`

Comment: yes, I read the documentation where it asks for a pure date and OHLC pair, I will reread. Thanks for the pointer, I have looked at the output. Hopefully fixing the date format will resolve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Beaches You can edit your own question to add new information. Don't make them as an answer. Answers are really meant to be answers. I edited your post and included the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clean up @Fraccalo's answer a bit:

```
(* Drop the first row as a header, and Import all but the last columns (Improved in 11.3) *)
data = Import["~/Desktop/test.csv", {"Data", All, 1 ;; -2}, "HeaderLines" -> 1]

CandlestickChart[
    (* CandlestickChart takes a date, then a list of open high low close, 
      so map over each row, interpret the first column as a DateTime 
      and group the remaining 4 columns. *)
    {Interpreter["DateTime"][First[#]], Rest[#]} & /@ data
]
```

I've noticed Interpreter can be a bit slow, so this is a slightly faster approach. Turns out this seems to work, but issue a message:

```
DateObject["15/10/10 0:10"]
```

So it's possibly less reliable, but this does produce the same results for the data given above:

```
CandlestickChart[
    {Quiet[DateObject[First[#]]], Rest[#]} & /@ data
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a = Import["book1.csv"];
aPlot = {DateObject[{#[[1]], {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year", " ", 
    "Hour", ":", "Minute"}}], #[[2 ;; -2]]} & /@ a[[2 ;;]];
CandlestickChart[aPlot]
```

Note that I'm ignoring the Volume data, as the CandlestickChart says that ChandlestickChart takes data in the form:

```
{{Subscript[date, 1],{Subscript[open, 1],Subscript[high, 1],Subscript[low, 1],Subscript[close, 1]}}
```

I'm not sure it's exactly what you are looking for (and I'm not familiar with CandlestickChart), but you can try this as a starting point for doing what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, this has got be going.